# Cubic root of an element in a field?

Tags: field-theory

In my textbook, I see the mentioning of the cubic root of an element in a field with the notation $\sqrt[3]{a}$ for $a \in F$ with $F$ being a field.

I am not sure if I intepreted this correctly: $\sqrt[3]{a}$ are referring to the three roots of the polynomial $x^3 - a$ in its splitting field over $F$.

Please confirm if my understanding was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually refers to *one* of the roots, chosen either arbitrarily or following some general principle. For instance, for real numbers, we choose $\sqrt[3]{a}$ to denote the *real* root of $x^3-a$, not any of the two other complex roots. On the other hand, for a field like $\Bbb F_7$, there is no significant difference between the three choices for $\sqrt[3]{2}$, so we just pick one of them.

Comment: I need to prove that some extension $K$ of $F$ is not equal to $F(\sqrt[3]{a})$ for all $a \in F$. With that sense, I need to prove that for all $a \in F$, every root $\alpha$ of $x^3 - a$ in its splitting field over $F$, when added into $F$ to form $F(\alpha)$, must not equal to $K$. Did I intepret your answer correctly, sir?

Comment: @ElementX That seems like an entirely different question than the one you originally posted. If that's what you were really wondering about, why didb't you post that as your question?

Comment: Yes, that was the core of my problem, sir. Maybe I oversimlified things too much.